# Process DOM elements with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, dom, phantomjs

I'd like to load the full DOM of a website and process each element later. The example code / testcase is going to log all tags of a website.

This works perfect inside a normal browser:

```
var dom = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
    i;

for (i in dom)
{
    console.log(dom[i] && dom[i].tagName ? dom[i].tagName : 'invalid');
}
```

This testcase logs:

```
HTML
BODY
DIV
...etc...
```

This doesn't work inside PHANTOMJS:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('https://google.com', function ()
{
    var dom = page.evaluate(function ()
        {
            return document.getElementsByTagName('*');
        }),
        i;

    for (i in dom)
    {
        console.log(dom[i] && dom[i].tagName ? dom[i].tagName : 'invalid');
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

For some reason, only the very first object contains values. Therefore this testcase logs:

```
HTML
invalid
invalid
...
```

Help is wanted! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> Note: The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must
>   be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be
>   serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will not work!

Finally, I found the answer... just prepare and return a simple object inside the **evaluate** method.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('https://google.com', function ()
{
    var dom = page.evaluate(function ()
        {
            var temp =  document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
                tempArray = [],
                j;

            for (j in temp)
            {
                tempArray.push(
                {
                    tagName: temp[j].tagName,
                    className: temp[j].className
                });
            }
            return tempArray;
        }),
        i;

    for (i in dom)
    {
        console.log(dom[i] && dom[i].tagName ? dom[i].tagName : 'invalid');
        console.log(dom[i] && dom[i].className ? dom[i].className : 'invalid');
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```